# How to stringify socket-Object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, socket.io, stringify

I am developing an application, for which I need to send the socket objects themselves.
With socket object I mean the following: if I got an event, lets say
`s.on('message'...`, the socket object is `s`. So lets say I got the following code:

```
s.on('message', () => {
 send(JSON.stringify(s))
})
```

When executing this, I get the following error:

```
node:internal/child_process/serialization:127
    const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
                   ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Namespace'
    |     property 'server' -> object with constructor 'Server'
    --- property 'sockets' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

So as I understand, a socket object as I have it is a circular structure. I understand that I cant convert this to JSON straight away, so I tried [flatted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted) and [Circular JSON](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json/#circularjson), but both of them do change the object when I parse it back to use it. With the changes they make, I cant use the socket anymore, so this does not solve my problem.

Does anybody have any other ideas, how to stringify a socket object? Or at least how to modify it in a way that it gets able to be stringified and parsed back and be able to emit events.

Thanks

Robert

EDIT:
originally, the socket object looks like this and this is what I want to recreate:

```
<ref *1> Socket {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { hello: [Function (anonymous)] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  nsp: <ref *2> Namespace {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { connection: [Function (anonymous)] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    sockets: Map(1) { 'Nt7rlvbOutoSoJSwAAAB' => [Circular *1] },
    _fns: [],
    _ids: 0,
    server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _nsps: [Map],
      parentNsps: Map(0) {},
      _path: '/socket.io',
      clientPathRegex: /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.msgpack|\.esm)?(\.min)?\.js(\.map)?(?:\?|$)/,
      _connectTimeout: 45000,
      _serveClient: true,
      _parser: [Object],
      encoder: Encoder {},
      _adapter: [class Adapter extends EventEmitter],
      sockets: [Circular *2],
      opts: {},
      eio: [Server],
      httpServer: [Server],
      engine: [Server],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    name: '/',
    adapter: Adapter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      nsp: [Circular *2],
      rooms: [Map],
      sids: [Map],
      encoder: Encoder {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  client: Client {
    sockets: Map(1) { 'Nt7rlvbOutoSoJSwAAAB' => [Circular *1] },
    nsps: Map(1) { '/' => [Circular *1] },
    server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _nsps: [Map],
      parentNsps: Map(0) {},
      _path: '/socket.io',
      clientPathRegex: /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.msgpack|\.esm)?(\.min)?\.js(\.map)?(?:\?|$)/,
      _connectTimeout: 45000,
      _serveClient: true,
      _parser: [Object],
      encoder: Encoder {},
      _adapter: [class Adapter extends EventEmitter],
      sockets: [Namespace],
      opts: {},
      eio: [Server],
      httpServer: [Server],
      engine: [Server],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    conn: Socket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      id: '5mpvsEPeh5XBZWdWAAAA',
      server: [Server],
      upgrading: false,
      upgraded: false,
      _readyState: 'open',
      writeBuffer: [],
      packetsFn: [],
      sentCallbackFn: [],
      cleanupFn: [Array],
      request: [IncomingMessage],
      protocol: 4,
      remoteAddress: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
      checkIntervalTimer: null,
      upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
      pingTimeoutTimer: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 45000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 10339,
        _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: true,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 67,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 38
      },
      pingIntervalTimer: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 25000,
        _idlePrev: [Timeout],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 10324,
        _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: true,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 49,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 0
      },
      transport: [WebSocket],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    encoder: Encoder {},
    decoder: Decoder { _callbacks: [Object] },
    id: '5mpvsEPeh5XBZWdWAAAA',
    onclose: [Function: bound onclose],
    ondata: [Function: bound ondata],
    onerror: [Function: bound onerror],
    ondecoded: [Function: bound ondecoded],
    connectTimeout: undefined
  },
  data: {},
  connected: true,
  acks: Map(0) {},
  fns: [],
  flags: {},
  server: <ref *3> Server {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _nsps: Map(1) { '/' => [Namespace] },
    parentNsps: Map(0) {},
    _path: '/socket.io',
    clientPathRegex: /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.msgpack|\.esm)?(\.min)?\.js(\.map)?(?:\?|$)/,
    _connectTimeout: 45000,
    _serveClient: true,
    _parser: {
      protocol: 5,
      PacketType: [Object],
      Encoder: [class Encoder],
      Decoder: [class Decoder extends Emitter]
    },
    encoder: Encoder {},
    _adapter: [class Adapter extends EventEmitter],
    sockets: <ref *2> Namespace {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      sockets: [Map],
      _fns: [],
      _ids: 0,
      server: [Circular *3],
      name: '/',
      adapter: [Adapter],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    opts: {},
    eio: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      clients: [Object],
      clientsCount: 2,
      opts: [Object],
      ws: [WebSocketServer],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    httpServer: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 2,
      _handle: [Object],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '4:null:3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 6
    },
    engine: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      clients: [Object],
      clientsCount: 2,
      opts: [Object],
      ws: [WebSocketServer],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  adapter: <ref *4> Adapter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    nsp: <ref *2> Namespace {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      sockets: [Map],
      _fns: [],
      _ids: 0,
      server: [Server],
      name: '/',
      adapter: [Circular *4],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    rooms: Map(1) { 'Nt7rlvbOutoSoJSwAAAB' => [Set] },
    sids: Map(1) { 'Nt7rlvbOutoSoJSwAAAB' => [Set] },
    encoder: Encoder {},
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  id: 'Nt7rlvbOutoSoJSwAAAB',
  handshake: {
    headers: {
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0',
      accept: '*/*',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'sec-websocket-version': '13',
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      'sec-websocket-extensions': 'permessage-deflate',
      'sec-websocket-key': '2vQZM3MFKryEsev9TQKHaw==',
      connection: 'keep-alive, Upgrade',
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'websocket',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'websocket',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
      'sec-gpc': '1',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      upgrade: 'websocket'
    },
    time: 'Wed Aug 03 2022 23:03:34 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)',
    address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
    xdomain: true,
    secure: false,
    issued: 1659560614062,
    url: '/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket',
    query: [Object: null prototype] { EIO: '4', transport: 'websocket' },
    auth: {}
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Comment: You can't send sockets, they represent you networking device's socket that's being used for data transport. Sending a socket wouldn't make any sense. So: what makes you think you have to send this entire object, as opposed to just packing up the exact information needed by whatever you're sending data off to? I.e. "what are you trying to even _do_?"

Comment: I need to send the socket because I need it later on to emit an answer, so I just need socket.emit(). I thought about storing the needed information only, but have not found, which those information are...

Comment: Sorry: _what_ needs to emit an answer? Because whatever received the event, by definition, already has a reference to the socket that it can use to send data back. Give https://socket.io/get-started/chat a(nother) read-through to understand how socket.io works in terms of concrete code.

Comment: Yeah, I did not mention why I need to send it, sorry. The application is running an node.js-Cluster. One of the tasks is very memory intensive, therefore it is only executed by the master-process. This means the following: the worker process gets the event, sends a message to the master (which should include the socket and therefore it needs to be stringified) and than, after some computations, the master should answer. For this answer, I need the socket or at least the parts of the socket, that are needed for emit().

Comment: You don't: make the master send the data to your worker to do the work, have the worker send the result back to the master, and then have the master turn that into a socket answer using the socket it still has. Your master does the socket work, your worker just does data crunching or whatever it needs to do to get the data necessary to form a response.

Comment: I am not sure if the master is able to receive the event. Anyways, memory-wise it is not possible to have the workers to do the work, since the work is based on some maps which are at about 2 GB, so having every worker own an own copy of the map would take 8 GB of memory, which I dont have.

Comment: The point is that the socket owner delegates the work, something does the work, sends the data necessary to forms the response, and then the socket owner sends the response. You don't send "the socket", because that's literally impossible. Treat the call-to-work as an internal API call: it's just something that has to happen before a response can be sent over the socket, and your processes/cluster nodes can figure out without affecting who owns the socket and is going to respond with it.